# Populate Excel sheet column into Database Tables in ADF

Tags: excel, database, oracle-adf

I am trying to populate cells from excel sheet to tables in ADF. I have searched so much but I am getting references for Export to Excel but not Export from Excel to tables. So please suggest me some materials or ways how to get values from cells to variables in ADF and populate to database tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got solution:
We can Use Apache POI

```
        InputStream myxls =
            new FileInputStream("C:\\data.xls");
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(myxls);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0); // first sheet
        Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
        while (rows.hasNext()) {
            HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow)rows.next();
            Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
            while (cells.hasNext()) {
                HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell)cells.next();
            while (cells.hasNext()) {
                HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell)cells.next();
                   }
            }
```

HSSFWorkbook will support Excel 97-2003 For latest version you can go with XSSFWorkbook.